# Dynamic update the setState (Object) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, setstate

I have a state

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          qualification: {
            fieldOfStudy: "Architecture",
            degree: "",
          }
        };
      }
```

and I would like to update the state value dynamically on function call

```
onChange={this.handleChangeObj("qualification")}
```

Here is the function I have written:

```
handleChangeObj = (ObjName) => ({ target }) => {

//String Value - Qualification
console.log("handleChangeObj -> ObjName", ObjName);

//fieldOfStudy: Architecture
    console.log((target.name + ":" + target.value));

// Doubt over here how to update the value for qualification.fieldOfStudy : Architecture
    this.setState(() => ({
      ...this.state.ObjName,
      [target.name]: [target.value],
    }));

    // this is not working.
this.setState({ [ObjName.target.name]: target.value });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter being passed to the outer function, so all you need to do is to reference that in bracket notation:

```
this.setState({
  [ObjName]: {
    ...this.state[ObjName],
    [target.name]: [target.value]
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error

 Uncaught TypeError: ObjName.target is undefined

The above solution is not working for me. can suggest alternative one.

Comment: `ObjName.target` is not being used anywhere in my code. Make sure you copy it exactly, eg: `[target.name]: [target.value]`. The target is not a property of the `ObjName`, it's a standalone variable.